# Django - multiple inline forms validate 1 formset using another formset data

Tags: django, validation, django-forms, django-views, inline-formset

I have a main Model:

`MainModel` -> `MainModelForm` that's used in a view

I also have 2 inline forms that have the `MainModel` as primary key
`InlineModel1` => `InlineModel1Form (formset = CustomInlineModel1Formset(BaseInlineFormset))` which has it's own set of validations. It is a 1 or none setup, I.e. it's not required, but once it's added, it has some validations in place. Using the CustomSetup from BaseInlineFormSet is working great.

However, I have another model -
 `InlineModel2` which is not required -  **until the user has entered atleast 1 row in InLineModel1Form**. I'm losing hair over how to send/validate this, i.e using InlineModel1form data and check if there are any rows added, in InlineModel2Form
Form.

I need both set of inline forms setup separately, so a mixin showing everything in 1 place wouldn't work for me.

forms.py:

```
class CustomInlineModel2Formset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(CustomInlineModel2Formset, self).clean()

        if any(self.errors):
            return

        i=0
        # https://gist.github.com/nspo/cd26ae2716332234757d2c3b1f815fc2
        for form in self.forms:
            if(not form.is_valid()):
                continue
            if(form.cleaned_data and not form.cleaned_data.get('DELETE')):
                i = i+1
                print(form.cleaned_data)
                # Use data from request.POST/but from InlineModel1 and add error to field2 in InlineModel2
                # Ensure atleast 1 entry is here - so how to run validations, outside this loop?
    InlineModel2FormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(MainModel, InlineModel2,
        widgets = {},
        form=InlineModel2Form,
        formset = CustomInlineModel2Formset,
        exclude=[],
        min_num = 0, # min_num is to be validated as 1 only if InlineModel1Form has any entries added 
        max_num = 2,
        extra=0,
        can_delete=True,
        # formfield_callback=None
    )
```